# Display a chunked items list in Java 8

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream, chunked

With the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> items = 
             IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 23).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        final String s = items
            .stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
            .toString()
            .concat(".");

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I get:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23.

What I would like to do, is to break the line every 10 items, in order to get:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,

20,21,22,23.

I have try a lot of things after googling without any success !
Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Olivier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571715/is-there-a-java-8-equivalent-of-the-collate-method-in-grails/44584619#44584619

Comment: you can slightly adjust that answer to fit your needs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split list into multiple lists with fixed number of elements in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210775/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements-in-java-8)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But do I really need 50 lines for such a basic functionality ?

Comment: Writing your own Spliterator that takes the stream, groups the elements, and wraps itself in a new Stream is the usual way to go. For this specific example though, you could also write your own collector/reduction that produces a list of lists of numbers. When collecting the next number, check if there is space left in the last list, otherwise add a new empty list. Then stream the result, join the lists' elements with comma and the resulting strings with newline. The downside is that you produce a collection with all the elements, which might be a memory concern (Spliterator approach doesn't).

Comment: By the way, the last part of Holger's answer to the question @AlexisC. mentioned produces the reduction I mentioned in a really concise way. So if you can live with creating the intermediate collection, it is a pretty cool solution.

Comment: My two cents using StreamEx's groupRuns : `IntStreamEx.rangeClosed(0, 23).boxed().groupRuns((i1, i2) -> i1 / 10 == i2 / 10).collect(Collector.of(() -> new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator(), "", "."), (joiner, numbers) -> joiner.add(String.join(",", numbers.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new))), StringJoiner::merge, StringJoiner::toString));`

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to using a third-party library, the following will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) [`Collectors2.chunk(int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#chunk-int-).

```
String s = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 23)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors2.chunk(10))
        .collectWith(MutableList::makeString, ",")
        .makeString("", ",\n", ".");
```

The result of `Collectors2.chunk(10)` will be a `MutableList<MutableList<Integer>>`.  At this point I switch from the Streams APIs to using native Eclipse Collections APIs which are available directly on the collections.  The method `makeString` is similar to `Collectors.joining()`.  The method `collectWith` is like `Stream.map()` with the difference that a `Function2` and an extra parameter are passed to the method.  This allows a method reference to be used here instead of a lambda.  The equivalent lambda would be `list -> list.makeString(",")`.

If you use just Eclipse Collections APIs, this problem can be simplified as follows:

```
String s = Interval.zeroTo(23)
        .chunk(10)
        .collectWith(RichIterable::makeString, ",")
        .makeString("", ",\n", ".");
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is process these ascending numbers, you can do it like

```
String s = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 23).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i/10, LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(Object::toString, Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n", "", "."));
```

This solution can be adapted to work on an arbitrary random access list as well, e.g.

```
List<Integer> items = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 23).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

String s = IntStream.range(0, items.size()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i/10, LinkedHashMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(ix -> items.get(ix).toString(), Collectors.joining(","))))
    .values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n", "", "."));
```

However, there is no simple and elegant solution for arbitrary streams, a limitation which applies to all kind of tasks having a dependency to the element’s position.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an adaptation of the already linked in the comments `Collector`:

```
    private static Collector<String, ?, String> partitioning(int size) {
    class Acc {
        int count = 0;

        List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(String elem) {
            int index = count++ / size;
            if (index == list.size()) {
                list.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            list.get(index).add(elem);
        }

        Acc merge(Acc right) {

            List<String> lastLeftList = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            List<String> firstRightList = right.list.get(0);
            int lastLeftSize = lastLeftList.size();
            int firstRightSize = firstRightList.size();

            // they are both size, simply addAll will work
            if (lastLeftSize + firstRightSize == 2 * size) {
                System.out.println("Perfect!");
                list.addAll(right.list);
                return this;
            }

            // last and first from each chunk are merged "perfectly"
            if (lastLeftSize + firstRightSize == size) {
                System.out.println("Almost perfect");
                int x = 0;
                while (x < firstRightSize) {
                    lastLeftList.add(firstRightList.remove(x));
                    --firstRightSize;
                }
                right.list.remove(0);
                list.addAll(right.list);
                return this;
            }

            right.list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(this::add);
            return this;
        }

        public String finisher() {
            return list.stream().map(x -> x.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.joining(",\n"), x -> x + "."));
        }

    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::finisher);
}
```

And usage would be:

```
String result = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 24)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .collect(partitioning(10));
```